# How to easily access tabular data with arrays/objects/JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm working on an issue where I need to access the value and name of a buitenunit, binnenunit and boiler when certain conditions are met.

I have 4 different tables like this (almost similar) and when a condition is met I need to start searching data in 1 of the 4 tables. Take this table for example.

```
alpha|    buitenunit              binnenunit              boiler
-----------------------------------------------------------------
4200 |    ERLQ004CV3(value=100)   EHBH04C3V(value=101)    EHVH04S18C3V=(102)
6200 |    ERLQ006CV3(value=200)   EHBH04C3V(value=101)    EHVH04S18C3V=(102)
8200 |    ERLQ008CV3(value=300)   EHBH04C3V(value=101)    EHVH04S18C3V=(102)
11200|    ERLQ011CV3(value=400)   EHBH04C3V(value=101)    EHVH04S18C3V=(102)
14200|    ERLQ014CV3(value=500)   EHBH04C3V(value=101)    EHVH04S18C3V=(102)
```

Now I need corresponding buitenunit, binnenunit and boiler (and their values) depending on the alpha value.

For example, say alpha is 4200 then I need to show: "Your selected setup will be ERLQ004CV3, EHBH04C3V and EHVH04S18C3V and it will cost you (100+101+102) 303 coins.

For the moment I'm really confused how to get both value and name in way so I can easily access them.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var alphas = ['4200', '6200', '8200', '11200', '14200', '17000'];
var buitenunit = ['ERLQ004CV3', 'ERLQ006CV3', 'ERLQ008CV3', 'ERLQ011CV3', 'ERLQ014CV3', 'ERLQ016CV3'];
var binnenunit = ['EHBH04C3V', 'EHBH08C3V', 'EHBH08C3V', 'EHBH16C3V', 'EHBH16C3V', 'EHBH16C3V'];
var boiler = ['EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3'];
var grid = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < alphas.length; i++){
        var alpha = alphas[i];
        if(alpha in grid == false){
            grid[alpha] = {};
        }

        var buitenunit = buitenunitlinksboven[i];
        grid[alpha][buitenunit] = i;
        var binnenunit = binnenunitlinksboven[i];
        grid[alpha][binnenunit] = i;
        var boiler = boilerlinksboven[i];
        grid[alpha][boiler] = i;
    }
```

But now the only way to access the value is if I already know the name of a unit. And the name is dependant on the alpha value.

So my question is:
How would I store this kind of information in a way that it is easy accessible. Am I currently on the right track? I just thought of JSON, can JSON help me perhaps?

Amazing thanks to anybody taking the time to actually read this.

Greetings

Comment: So you want to look it up by any of (alpha, buitenunit, binnenunit or boiler) ?  Is it true that name and value are always a pair - that is : EHVH04S18C3V always means 102?

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

First - build a map of names to values.  This assumes the name and value are always a pair and you can look up one from the other.

```
// first build a map of names to their value
var valueLookupTable = {
  ERLQ004CV3:100,
  ERLQ006CV3:200,
  ERLQ008CV3:300,
  ERLQ011CV3:400,
  ERLQ014CV3:500,
  EHBH04C3V:101,
  EHVH04S18C3V:102
};
```

Then your grid builder could look more like this

```
var alphas = ['4200', '6200', '8200', '11200', '14200', '17000'];
var buitenunit = ['ERLQ004CV3', 'ERLQ006CV3', 'ERLQ008CV3', 'ERLQ011CV3', 'ERLQ014CV3', 'ERLQ016CV3'];
var binnenunit = ['EHBH04C3V', 'EHBH08C3V', 'EHBH08C3V', 'EHBH16C3V', 'EHBH16C3V', 'EHBH16C3V'];
var boiler = ['EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3'];

var grid = {};

var nn = alphas.length;
var ii = 0;
 for(; ii < nn; ++ii) {
  var alpha = alphas[ii]
  var entry = { 
    buitenunit : buitenunit[ii],
    binnenunit : binnenunit[ii],
    boiler : boiler[ii]
  }
  /** compute value for that entry by looking up values in the lookup table */
  var val = 0;
  for(var key in entry) {
    val += (valueLookupTable[entry[key]] || 0)
  }
  entry.value = val;
  grid[alpha] = entry;
}
```

Now when you do

```
grid[4200]
```

you get

```
{ buitenunit: "ERLQ004CV3", 
  binnenunit: "EHBH04C3V", 
  boiler: "EKHWS200B3V3", 
  value: 201}
```

where value is the sum of all the items.

If you needed individual values, you can look them up using the item by doing something like

```
var entry = grid[4200]
var binnenunitValue = valueLookupTable[entry.binnenunit];
```

Does this address the issue?

Note: I ran this and got the math to work out for me, but it looks like the `valueLookupTable` is missing some data.  I suspect your table in the example is not quite complete as I noticed that all the boiler records were the same.  But in your grid builder code, there is clearly a longer array of values.  No matter.  If the `valueLookupTable` has all of them, the rest should work out just fine.  It just means you'll need to flesh out that table with the correct values.

### Update

If the unit arrays have corresponding value arrays, you could use the following to build the `valueLookupTable` based on the arrays with something like this:

```
// if you're using underscore.js or jQuery you could use their `extend` method
var hashMerge = function(dest, src) {
  for (var property in src) {
    if (src.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       dest[property] = src[property];
    }
  }
  return dest;
};
var buildHash = function(keys,values) {
  var result = {};
  var nn = keys.length;
  var ii = 0;
  for (; ii < nn; ++ii) {
     result[keys[ii]]=values[ii];
  }
  return result;
};

var alphas = ['4200', '6200', '8200', '11200', '14200', '17000'];
var buitenUnits = ['ERLQ004CV3', 'ERLQ006CV3', 'ERLQ008CV3', 'ERLQ011CV3', 'ERLQ014CV3', 'ERLQ016CV3'];
var buitenValues = [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 ];
var binnenUnits = ['EHBH04C3V', 'EHBH08C3V', 'EHBH08C3V', 'EHBH16C3V', 'EHBH16C3V', 'EHBH16C3V'];
var binnenValues = [ 101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601 ];
var boilerUnits = ['EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3', 'EKHWS200B3V3']
var boilerValues = [ 102, 202, 302, 402, 502, 602 ];

var buittens = buildHash(buitenUnits, buitenValues);
var binnens = buildHash(binnenUnits, binnenValues);
var boilers = buildHash(boilerUnits, boilerValues);

var valueLookupTable = hashMerge( buittens, hashMerge(binnens, boilers));
```

The rest should be the same.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed what I needed. The only problem I have is, my values are also in arrays, how do i link them to the units. For example alpha 4200, buitenunit(value=buitenunitvaluearray[0]), binnenunit(value=binnenunitvaluearray[0]), etc. Thanks a bunch for the help btw, very clear!

Comment: Could if the bittenunit array store both key/value?  like this `val bittenunits = [ {EHBH04C3V: 100}, {EHBH04C4V: 200} ... ]` (i'm making up the numbers here, but just to see if conceptually that'll work.  If so, i think i could edit the answer to have a solution for that.